How can one thread portably wait for something to happen in another in a way that's reliably interruptible by a signal handler running?
POSIX supports lots of ways for threads in concurrent programs to wait for things to happen in other threads, e.g., mutexes, condition variables, and semaphores. Unfortunately, none of those particular three things can be reliably interrupted by a signal handler running:

pthread_mutex_lock says "If a signal is delivered to a thread waiting for a mutex, upon return from the signal handler the thread shall resume waiting for the mutex as if it was not interrupted."
pthread_cond_wait says "If a signal is delivered to a thread waiting for a condition variable, upon return from the signal handler the thread resumes waiting for the condition variable as if it was not interrupted, or it shall return zero due to spurious wakeup."
sem_wait says that it may fail with EINTR if a signal interrupts it (as opposed to other errors that say it shall fail).

For pthread_cond_wait and sem_wait, in addition to it being optional for the implementation to allow interruption at all, there's also a race condition even for ones that do: if a signal handler runs right before they start waiting, it will be too late to not start waiting, but too early for the wait to be interrupted. (This is the same race condition that makes pselect necessary, rather than pthread_sigmask immediately followed by select being an acceptable substitute.)
Is there any reasonable way to do this in POSIX that isn't really heavyweight (e.g., using pipes, so 2 FDs per mutex/semaphore/whatever, and pselect for all waits)? If not, then what about Linux-specific ways?

With linux, you can use eventfd() instead of pipes for a select/poll'able notification.
